# Why don't my Sims move in together when they get married?

Tags: the-sims-3

This has happened to me with two different sims now. I have every EP except Seasons and the stuff packs. My sim will get married, but no dialogue will pop up to combine the families - I have to do it manually from Edit Town, which kind of ruins it.

Comment: [trolling] You are sure that this is true love? [/trolling]

Comment: I hope it's a glitch, but it's happened to me with two different sims (in two different towns) as well. And my friend just had it happen with her sim. It just started up after the patch that came after Seasons. The best advice I can give is to try to get the 'move in together' interaction. But that's a very hard to get interaction, in my experience. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

definitely sounds like a bug, but getting them to move in together isnt that hard through convo, just have to cycle through friendly options until the conversation reaches a 'friendly' level